# Llenar DataGridView en C# desde consulta a su respectiva columna

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo un componente DataGridView en .NET al cual le he asignado las columnas que deseo muestre. Y luego tengo:

```
internal class ModelArticulos
{
    private DataTable? dt;
    public string cadenaConexion= "Server=localhost;Database=gestion;Uid=root;Pwd=;";
    public DataSet Listar()
    {
        MySqlConnection mSqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(cadenaConexion);
        mSqlConnection.Open();
        string sql = "select * from productos;";
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
        adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter (sql,mSqlConnection);
        adapter.Fill(ds,"tbl");
        return ds;
    }
}
```

En mi modelArticulos.cs pero el tema es como asigno cada resultado del query de mysql a su correspondiente columna del dataGridView.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para enlazar un **DataGridView** a un **DataSet** debes tener en cuenta que un **DataSet** contiene un conjunto de **DataTables**, por tanto debes especificar a que **DataTable** del **DataSet** quieres enlazar el **DataGridView**, esto lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
var ds = Listar();

miDataGrid.Datasource = ds;
miDataGrid.DataMember = "tbl";
```

Lo que haces aquí es guardar en la **variable ds** el **DataSet** que retorna tú **método Listar** y después debes especificar el **DataTable** dentro de ese **DataSet** al que quieres enlazar tú **DataGridView**, para especificar este **DataTable** usas la **propiedad DataMember** del **DataGridView**.

También puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
miDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables["tbl"];
```

Aquí accedes a la **propiedad Tables** del **DataSet** y específicas el nombre del **DataTable** que quieres enlazar, en vez del nombre de la tabla también podrías poner su índice si te lo sabes:

```
miDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; //Pones el índice que corresponda
```

En lo particular te recomiendo que utilices el nombre de la tabla en lugar de su índice.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta..me funciono pero me pone los titulos de las columnas como los campos de la bd. Quisiera elegir los nombre de las columnas y asignarle un campo de la consulta

Comment: @Caruso dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Nombre"; ponlo despues de enlazar el grid al datasource

Comment: @Caruso si la respuesta te resulto util podrias darme tu voto, gracias

Comment: Ya lo hice muchas gracias

Comment: Como puedo aplicar un filtro incremental desde un  textbox sobre el dataset?

Comment: @Caruso te recomiendo que publiques una pregunta con esta nueva inquietud y ahi expliques con detalles lo que quieres hacer